# changing a linux users password

Tags: linux

I'd like to execute a command on a remote vm that creates a user and specifies their password.

using sshpass, I can remotely execute commands as root, e.g.

```
sshpass -p "rootpasswd" ssh root@remotevm '<remote command here>'
```

So I want to create a user, which I can do with

```
adduser <username>
```

Next I want to use usermod to create a password:

```
usermod --password <encrypted_pass> <user>
```

I want to be able to specify the password bananas - so how can I encrypt the string bananas so that I can specify bananas as the encrypted password for the user?

Comment: This question was asked in relation to bash scripting - which while unix related is programming.

Comment: you can try by using gpg symmetric encryption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`chpasswd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chpasswd):

```
echo "user:password_here" | chpasswd
```

Comment: works.  accept in 6 mins ;)

Answer (score 6):

As root, you can set a password for the user:

```
passwd username
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use usermod to change the password.  Use passwd instead.

```
sudo passwd <user>
```

Comment: I want to execute the command remotely via ssh

Comment: this requires terminal interaction which I specifically need to avoid